# C#: Unknown constructor 'Parameter(String, TypeCode, Int)' of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In my code behind I have the code below to execute an insert command.  Two of the parameter values are to be set when the user clicks a particular button.  I broke it out this way because I'd like to reuse the `SqlDataSource`.

My problem is with this line `(@"Amount", TypeCode.Int16, amount)`.  The specific error is `C#: Unknown constructor Parameter(String, TypeCode, Int) of System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter`.  Can someone point out what I did wrong? Or, please tell me what steps I can take to debug this.  I'm stuck.

```
    protected void InsertFees_Inserting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = Convert.ToInt16(RadGrid1.SelectedValues["UserID"].ToString());
    e.Command.Parameters["@Type"].Value = "D";
    e.Command.Parameters["@Date"].Value = DateTime.Now;
    e.Command.Parameters["@Amount"].Value = "";
    e.Command.Parameters["@Description"].Value = "";
}

protected void RadButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        int amount = Convert.ToInt16(RadNumericTextBox1.Text);
        InsertFees.InsertParameters.Add(new Parameter("@Amount", TypeCode.Int16, amount));
        InsertFees.InsertParameters.Add(new Parameter("@Description", TypeCode.String, RadTextBox2.Text));
        InsertFees.Insert();
        Label2.Text = "Insert Successful";
    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        Label3.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to patch the `.NET framework` on the server since this function was included in .NET 2.0 in a later Service Pack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with `Bemused` answer, but you need to pass the parameters to your SQLDataSource in this way.

```
InsertFees.InsertParameters["Amount"].DefaultValue = amount.ToString();
```

as you are adding parameters like..`InsertFees.InsertParameters.Add(new Parameter("@Amount", TypeCode.Int16, amount));`, It will add parameters again into Insert Parameters collection, which you have already defined in SQLDataSource InsertParameter collection

Comment: Thanks.  How do I specify the dbtype in the above code? It's expecting a string and I need to give it an int.

Comment: You can use amount.ToString() and pass the value, Since DefaultValue property require String value, But SQLDataSource Automatically hanlde this, what you have mention in your SQLDataSource Insert Parameter collection.

Answer (score 2):

*int* is an Int32, while Int16 is a *Short*

```
int amount
```

Maybe try this instead?

```
short amount = Convert.ToInt16(RadNumericTextBox1.Text);
InsertFees.InsertParameters.Add(new Parameter("@Amount", TypeCode.Int16, amount));
```

Or another way...

```
int amount = Convert.ToInt32(RadNumericTextBox1.Text);
InsertFees.InsertParameters.Add(new Parameter("@Amount", TypeCode.Int32, amount));
```

---

http://www.dotnetperls.com/int16-int32-int64

Comment: Thanks...I didn't realize int is int32.  Learned something today.  Unfortunately the proposed fix returns the same error.